# How to limit application memory usage?

Tags: linux, memory

I have spent 2 hours reading questions about this matter, and still there is some misunderstanding.

I have this process:

```
USER PID %CPU %MEM VSZ RSS TTY STAT START TIME COMMAND    
root 1452 0.4 1.8 1397012 19308 ? Sl 04:23 3:48 ./transaction_server
```

This shows it uses 19.3MB of system resident memory (I have no swap file), and around 1.8% of the whole 1GB system memory, but the virtual size is 1.39GB?!? I have read that `ulimit -m` doesn't work. People use `ulimit -v` to set virtual memory limit for the process. Is this virtual memory is the one VSZ listed with `ps`? What value I should set if I want to restrict this process to use 100MB system memory at most? I have read documentation for `setrlimit` and this seems legit:

```
RLIMIT_AS
        This  is  the maximum size of a process' total available memory, 
        in bytes. If this limit is exceeded, the malloc() and mmap() 
        functions shall fail with errno set to [ENOMEM]. In addition, 
        the automatic stack growth fails with the effects outlined above.
```

But other versions of the documentation say this `RLIMIT_AS` parameter sets virtual memory size. What is the truth?

Comment: Please, pay some attention to post formatting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, VSZ is virtual memory. As to RLIMIT_AS, where did you find the paragraph quoted above? Since setrlimit(2) is a Linux system call, I do not see how it could possibly monitor malloc(3), a library function. Instead, it can only work with brk(2), sbrk(2), and mmap(2) -- this is also what its manpage (checked of Scientific Linux) suggests. However, the total amount of memory requested via these functions *is* virtual memory, so RLIMIT_AS indeed limits virtual memory. (This is, again, in accordance with the setrlimit(2) manpage.)

Unfortunately, you cannot limit RSS under Linux (this would be `ulimit -m`). You can try `ulimit -d` (RLIMIT_DATA), but this will include mmap(2) only since Linux 4.7, typically used for large allocations. Another possibility would be to limit virtual memory, but with such a large difference between RSS and VSZ, this might be difficult.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
The paragraph is from `setrlimit` man page `IEEE/The Open Group                                                                     2003                                                                          GETRLIMIT(3P)`
How come `ps` can show me the RSS, but the kernel can't enforce limit on it?

Comment: According to Alan Cox, this has historical reasons: calculating RSS used to be expensive, so enforcing the limit would put a large load on the kernel; source: http://linux.derkeiler.com/Mailing-Lists/Kernel/2006-01/msg03306.html. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3043709/resident-set-size-rss-limit-has-no-effect/6365534#6365534

Comment: I see. I guess I would go with `ulimit -d` then. The application is written by me, and I didn't use `mmap()`.

Comment: No, you usually don't (nor sbrk()), but malloc() might.

Comment: I see. That is very unfortunate. So the solution to this question then, is either cgroups, or memory usage poll with some script language.

Comment: `malloc()` is a library call but gets its memory from mmap or brk/sbrk. If the system call fails (e.g. due to ulimit restrictions) `malloc` will also report a failure.

Comment: Since Linux 4.7 mmap() allocated memory is included into data (RLIMIT_DATA).

Answer (score 5):

Many processes share some of its memory with other processes, e.g. libc is used by nearly every process but only mapped in memory once, but it counts towards the virtual memory usage of every process. Limiting memory usage that's only used by a certain process (mostly RSS) can be done using cgroups. See answers to [How to limit the total resources (memory) of a process and its children](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134414/how-to-limit-the-total-resources-memory-of-a-process-and-its-children/174894) for how to do it. This will limit the total memory of a process and its children.