# systemd memory limit not working/example

Tags: systemd, memory, out-of-memory

I'm trying to use the [systemd infrastructure](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.resource-control.html) to kill my memory leaking service when its memory usage reaches some value. The configuration file used is this:

```
[Unit]
Description="Start memory gobbler"
After=network.target
MemoryAccounting=true
MemoryHigh=1024K
MemoryMax=4096K

[Service]
ExecStart=/data/memgoble 8388600
```

`systemd` version is 237.
However, no matter what I set in the `MemoryMax` the kernel would kill the process on its own terms, usually when its memory consumption reaches almost the entire physical RAM. I'm running this on an embedded system with no swap.

Anyone sees an obvious error in the configuration? Perhaps there are some other settings that I'm missing.

Comment: Have you considered using `ulimit` older simpler, and should work in this case.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a choice in this matter. `systemd` is the only option. Based on the man page the `MemoryMax` should work for a service. It just doesn't for some reason.

Comment: you do have an option to **consider it**. It looks like you did.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor `ulimit` doesn't work for memory restrictions. The last kernel to support it (RLIMIT_RSS) was 2.4.30, which is 12 years old. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/32375/4358

Comment: I also had the error: Unknown lvalue 'MemoryMax' in section 'Service' I have an older version of systemd and so I had to use MemoryLimit instead of MemoryMax.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have the config parameters in the wrong section.

If you look in your logs, you should see:

```
Unknown lvalue 'MemoryAccounting' in section 'Unit'
Unknown lvalue 'MemoryHigh' in section 'Unit'
Unknown lvalue 'MemoryMax' in section 'Unit'
```

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.resource-control.html

> The resource control configuration options are configured in the [Slice], [Scope], [Service], [Socket], [Mount], or [Swap] sections, depending on the unit type.

Thus you want:

```
[Unit]
Description="Start memory gobbler"
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/data/memgoble 8388600
MemoryAccounting=true
MemoryHigh=1024K
MemoryMax=4096K
```

Comment: Good catch @Patrick. I did the change you suggested, but still get these errors:
`Jun 12 19:15:52 intel-corei7-64 systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/memgoble.service: Unknown lvalue 'MemoryHigh' in section 'Service'`
`Jun 12 19:15:52 intel-corei7-64 systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/memgoble.service: Unknown lvalue 'MemoryMax' in section 'Service'`
Which is strange because based on the `systemd` manual this is where the configuration should reside.

Comment: Check the man page on your system. Note the comments in the linked man page such as "MemoryMax= replaces MemoryLimit=" and others. The linked man page is the very latest version. Your system might not be running that version.

Comment: Yeap, the `systemd` version I thought I've had was actually much older, that was the problem.

Comment: PSA: This version mismatch issue is a _very_ common source of confusion.  Note that a hugely popular distro like RHEL 7 and basically all derivatives (CentOS 7, Amazon Linux 2, etc.) are still stuck on version `219`!  My personal favorite trick for exploring supported directives is to grep through the `systemd.directives` man page like this: `man systemd.directives | grep -A 2 -i memory`.  For instance, that cmd tells me I can learn about `MemoryLimit` with `man systemd.resource-control`.