# Limit a process's memory by name forever

Tags: linux, ubuntu, memory, ram

I am developing using webpack. The problem is, my current project is huge, and takes around 6GB of memory (~30% of RAM according to top).

Is it possible to run a command restricting it's memory persistently? It's important to note, it starts as root (tools we use - I know - it's very weird)

The problem is, that when there is too little memory, my machine just freezes. I am looking for any way to avoid the freezing. So maybe reserve 500mb for the system itself. I'm open to suggestions

Comment: looking at `ulimit`

Comment: @DanieleGrassini: you beat me to it.+1  ;-)

Comment: If your project is using systemd services/unit files to execute, you will want to refer to ````man systemd.resource-control```` rather than using ````ulimit```` or ````/etc/security/limits.conf```` to handle resource limits.

Comment: @ReedGhost: +1: can you develop that comment further ... as an answer ?

Comment: @Cbhihe Added as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

When establishing hard and/or soft limits with `ulimit [-H|S]`, once set *for a given shell* a hard limit cannot be modified by a non-root user. To do so a non-root process owner needs to stop execution, set a new limit and start again.

You'll need to specify the limit within your current project's execution shell. If you do so in a calling shell the limit set will apply to ALL processes started or spawned in that shell, *combined*. So with that in mind you might be interested in specifically setting the max stack size (`ulimit -H -s <limit>`) and/or the [max resident set size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60779604/4906636) (`ulimit -H -m <limit>` for max RSS).

RSS is the portion of memory occupied by a process that is held in physical memory.

You may or may not have access to the latter, depending on your system. (I do not have access to an Ubuntu OS right now to check... you might be out of luck.)

A caveat is that setting that limit, the behavior you get is not fully deterministic over replicated executions. Depending on what your system does at any given moment, it may decide to swap chunks of memory at different times from one execution to the next. In other words, it may reach a different values of RSS at different times across runs, e.g. when executing other unrelated processes concurrently.

Apart from the `ulimit` man page, also look at answer and comments [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/32375/72707).

Answer (score 0):

If your project(or the program which runs it) is a systemd service, slice, mount, or socket you will need to set resource limits within its service/slice/mount/socket file rather than setting it using `/etc/security/limits.conf` or `ulimit`.

You can find your systemd unit files in `/usr/lib/systemd/system/` or `/etc/systemd/system` depending on your distribution.

To quickly make edits you can use `systemctl edit <unit name>` to make 'drop-in' edits. Specifying `--full` with the previous command will allow you to view the full service file while you edit(Essentially editting a copy and a replacing).

For your particular question it would be advisable to set:

```
MemoryHigh=<Bytes>
```

You can think of this directive as specifying the throttling point of memory usage for your program. You can add K,M,G, or T as a suffix to the  to specify Kilobytes, Megabytes, Gigabytes, or Terabytes respectively.

You can also set:

```
MemoryMax=<Bytes>
```

Upon exceeding this directives value, an out-of-memory killer will invoked within the unit. The manpage for regarding these directives([systemd.resource-control](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.resource-control.html#)) recommends using this as a 'last line of defense`. You may also specify K,M,G,T as with the previous directive.

There's also a deprecated setting that preceded the two above directives called `MemoryLimit` which may be useful if you're not on a newer systemd release.

The two mentioned directives apply limits to the entire control group, which will prevent forking processes from being able to escape from the limits; However you can also set limits to the singular process using the `LimitAS` (Limit address space) directive.

An example service file using `MemoryHigh=` and `MemoryMax=`

```
[Unit]
Description=A foobar service that does foo and bar
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
MemoryHigh=2500M
MemoryMax=3000M
ExecStart=/usr/bin/foobar-daemon start
ExecStop=/usr/bin/foobar-daemon stop

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

For full description of directives or for additional information;

see [systemd.resource-control](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.resource-control.html#) or `man systemd.resource-control` and [systemd.exec](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#) or `man systemd.exec`

Comment: I tried running `sudo systemctl edit webpack`, but it said I need to run `sudo systemctl edit --force --full webpack.service` to create a unit. Is this correct? Also then, how do I "connect" webpack.service, with actual webpack process?

Comment: If you have to create a new unit for ````webpack````, this means either webpack is not being managed by systemd already or it is referred to by a different name; If this is the former case, I would suggest using ````/etc/security/limits.conf```` instead; However if you would like to configure webpack as a systemd service, you could refer to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/672615/290574)

Comment: If you think webpack is already managed by systemd but under a different name; You can look through all unit files with ````systemctl list-unit-files````